# Create an array that saves the quantities of an id and changes when you on click the button option

Tags: javascript

I have this code, it allows me to pick the quantities for the days and when I click on add to cart and go back to the meal, I can still see my quantities, but as you can see I have different meal options, is there a way to make the quantities consistent with the ids? that if my quantity for beef is 2 2 1, and then I go back to click chicken, it will start with the quantities I have for that meal option ?

```
<span> 
            <span class= "prices">
            $15.00 - $17.00         </span>
                    <div class="price-options">  

                    <span id = "price_option-1101" class="none prices">$15.00</span>



            </div>
                        <div class="price-options">  

                    <span id = "price_option-1102" class="none prices">$16.00</span>



            </div>
                        <div class="price-options">  

                    <span id = "price_option-1103" class="none prices">$17.00</span>



            </div>




           <br>
            </span>
            <button price=15 label_option= 1101 class="view1 white cbtn1 open_sansbold option protein-option">Tofu <span id="price-difference-for-1101"></span></button><button price=16 label_option= 1102 class="view1 white cbtn1 open_sansbold option protein-option">Chicken <span id="price-difference-for-1102"></span></button><button price=17 label_option= 1103 class="view1 white cbtn1 open_sansbold option protein-option">Beef <span id="price-difference-for-1103"></span></button>            </center>

            <br>
            <div class="textCenter" style="font-weight:700">
                Add this meal to the delivery days below:
                <br><br>
            </div>
            <table>

                    <div class="satin background_option">
                <p style="display:inline-block;margin-right:150px">Monday, May 15th</p>
                <span style="float:right;">
                    <i id="qty-minus1" class="fa fa-minus-circle controls" style="color: #d7d6d0"></i>
                    <input id="qty1" type="number" value="2" min="0" step="1" style="border:1px solid #d7d6d0;background:transparent;width:35px;height:33px;color:#000;font-size:21px;font-weight:700;">
                    <i id="qty-plus1" class="fa fa-plus-circle controls"  style="color: #d7d6d0"></i>
                </span>
            </div>

                            <div class="satin background_option" style="margin-top:10px;height:50px;">
                <p style="display:inline-block;margin-right:150px">Wednesday, May 17th</p>
                <span style="float:right;">
                    <i id="qty-minus3" class="fa fa-minus-circle controls" style="color: #d7d6d0"></i>
                    <input id="qty3" type="number" value="2" min="0" step="1" style="border:1px solid #d7d6d0;background:transparent;width:35px;height:33px;color:#000;font-size:21px;font-weight:700;">
                    <i id="qty-plus3" class="fa fa-plus-circle controls"  style="color: #d7d6d0"></i>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="satin background_option" style="margin-top:10px;height:50px;">
                <p style="display:inline-block;margin-right:150px">Friday, May 19th</p>
                <span style="float:right;">
                    <i id="qty-minus5" class="fa fa-minus-circle controls" style="color: #d7d6d0"></i>
                    <input id="qty5" type="number" value="3" min="0" step="1" style="border:1px solid #d7d6d0;background:transparent;width:35px;height:33px;color:#000;font-size:21px;font-weight:700;">
                    <i id="qty-plus5" class="fa fa-plus-circle controls"  style="color: #d7d6d0"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
                </table>
            <center>
            <a style="color:white;text-decoration:none;" href="../deliveries"><button class=" view-add white cbtn1 open_sansbold option">Back </button></a>
            <button id= "add-to-cart" class=" view-disable white cbtn1 open_sansbold option" disabled> ADD TO CART </button>
            </center>
            </article>
```

I already have this JavaScript to do the pricing on the buttons

```
$(".protein-option").click(function() {
        var this_id = $(this).attr("label_option");
        var this_price = parseInt($(this).attr("price"), 10);
        console.log("this_id" + this_id + "-- " + this_price);

        $("#totalprice").val($(this).attr("price"));

        $(".protein-option").each(function() {
            var loop_id = $(this).attr("label_option");
            var loop_price = parseInt($(this).attr("price"), 10);
            var difference = loop_price - this_price;
            var sign = Math.sign(difference);
            difference = Math.abs(difference);
            difference = parseFloat(difference).toFixed(2);
            if(sign == 0) {
                difference = "$0.00";
            } else if (sign == 1) {
                difference = "+$" + difference;
            } else if (sign == -1) {
                difference = "-$" + difference;
            }

            console.log(loop_id + " -- " + loop_price + " -- " + difference + " -- " + sign);
            $("#price-difference-for-"+loop_id).html(difference);
        });

        $("#price-difference-for-"+this_id).html(" ");
    });
```

I put this code after the onclick (I declared my array on the top of the page)

```
var meal_label_qty = $(this).attr("label_option");
var id_mon_qty = $("#qty1").val();
var id_tues_qty = $("#qty2").val();
var id_wed_qty = $("#qty3").val();
var id_thur_qty = $("#qty4").val();
var id_fri_qty = $("#qty5").val();

//gets meal id and qty
label_options.push(meal_label_qty);
qty_options.push(id_mon_qty,id_tues_qty,id_wed_qty,id_thur_qty,id_fri_qty);
meal_qty.push(label_options,qty_options);
alert(meal_qty);
```

I get the alerts correct, but how can I make them change depending on the label_option id?

here is how my code looks like 
[image]

Comment: *a **small** , complete and verifyable example*

Comment: This does work now @Jonasw

Comment: i didnt highlight *verifyable*

Comment: Okay no thanks, this is the only way my code works, thanks anyways @Jonasw

Comment: nope. You can remove all the PHP stuff and replace it with html as were on client side. Theres also a lot of html we dont need for solving your problem

Comment: You met something like this? @Jonasw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143794/discussion-between-sarah-and-jonas-w).

Comment: why? were not chating, have a look at my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you may want to store it in an object ( much better then searching an array ) and then restore on every change?

```
var quantperproduct={};
var meal_label_qty="1011";


$(".protein-option").on("click",function(){
    var elements=[1,2,3,4,5].map(el=>$("#qty"+el));
    var quantities=elements.map(el=>el.val());
    //store them:
    quantperproduct[meal_label_qty]=quantities;
    //restore the new label ( if possible) 
    meal_label_qty = $(this).attr("label_option");
    elements.forEach((el,i)=>el.val((quantperproduct[meal_label_qty]||[])[i]||0));
});
```

Comment: ok why did you put inside `var elements [1,2,3,4,5]` what should  I put?

Comment: @sarah elements contains [$("qty1"),...] ive just shortified the whole thing abit...

Comment: and var meal_label_aty cannot be identified before, because it gets identified on click

Comment: @sarah :/ you need a default value, you can if you want to  assign it dynamically, do that onload...

Comment: @sarah and there was a bracket missing in the last line, fixed that.

Comment: @sarah https://jsfiddle.net/t36nedjm/ generally working, just needs some improvements, but i think you can do that...

Comment: ok i made it work but for some reason friday isn't changing and when i leave the page, the qtys restart

Comment: @sarah : if you want it to be persistent have a look at *localStorage* ...